# Attribute "insetForeground" has already been defined in colors.xml?

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport

I have just imported Android Support Library

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
```

And Got error :

```
Error:(2) Attribute "insetForeground" has already been defined
```

I removed all libraries with Attribute "insetForeground" and now again getting same error:

Error:(2) Attribute "insetForeground" has already been defined

on

```
E:\Projects\Android\eSwasthya Project\Final Project\EswasthyaProjectV3\app\src\main\res\values\color.xml
```

my colors.xml doesn't contain any such attribute at all.

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="primary_reminder">#00bfb0</color>
    <color name="primary_dark_reminder">#1b9d93</color>

    <color name="primary">#2196F3</color>
    <color name="primary_trans">#a02196F3</color>
    <color name="primary_dark">#1976D2</color>
    <color name="primary_light">#BBDEFB</color>
    <color name="accent">#03A9F4</color>
    <color name="primary_text">#212121</color>
    <color name="secondary_text">#727272</color>
    <color name="divider">#B6B6B6</color>
    <color name="back">#eeeeee</color>
    <color name="red">#c62828</color>
    <color name="green">#43a047</color>
    <color name="green_trans">#4043a047</color>
    <color name="green_dark">#ff669900</color>
    <color name="gray">#ccc</color>
    <color name="grey_background">#55ededed</color>
    <color name="blue">#FF2196F3</color>

    <color name="indigo_500">#3f51b5</color>
    <color name="indigo_700">#303f9f</color>
    <color name="cyan_500">#00bcd4</color>
    <color name="baseColor">#009688</color>
    <color name="primaryColor">#2196f3</color>
    <color name="errorColor">#ddaa00</color>
    <color name="errorColor_dark">#DD7500</color>
    <color name="helperTextColor">#795548</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="onetimegreen">#88DE18</color>
    <color name="black_semi_transparent">#B2000000</color>
    <color name="ripple">#F06292</color>



    <integer-array name="colors">
        <item>@color/holo_blue_dark</item>
        <item>@color/holo_yellow_dark</item>
        <item>@color/holo_green_dark</item>
        <item>@color/holo_purple_dark</item>
        <item>@color/holo_red_dark</item>
    </integer-array>

    <integer-array name="gplus_colors">
        <item>@color/gplus_color_1</item>
        <item>@color/gplus_color_2</item>
        <item>@color/gplus_color_3</item>
        <item>@color/gplus_color_4</item>
    </integer-array>

    <integer-array name="pocket_bar_colors">
        <item>@color/pocket_color_1</item>
        <item>@color/pocket_color_1</item>
        <item>@color/pocket_color_1</item>
        <item>@color/pocket_color_1</item>
        <item>@color/pocket_color_2</item>
        <item>@color/pocket_color_2</item>
        <item>@color/pocket_color_2</item>
        <item>@color/pocket_color_2</item>
        <item>@color/pocket_color_3</item>
        <item>@color/pocket_color_3</item>
        <item>@color/pocket_color_3</item>
        <item>@color/pocket_color_3</item>
        <item>@color/pocket_color_4</item>
        <item>@color/pocket_color_4</item>
        <item>@color/pocket_color_4</item>
        <item>@color/pocket_color_4</item>
    </integer-array>

    <integer-array name="pocket_background_colors">
        <item>@color/pocket_color_1</item>
        <item>@color/pocket_color_2</item>
        <item>@color/pocket_color_3</item>
        <item>@color/pocket_color_4</item>
    </integer-array>

    <color name="pocket_color_1">#85edb9</color>
    <color name="pocket_color_2">#34bdb7</color>
    <color name="pocket_color_3">#ee4458</color>
    <color name="pocket_color_4">#fcb74d</color>

    <color name="gplus_color_1">#3e802f</color>
    <color name="gplus_color_2">#f4b400</color>
    <color name="gplus_color_3">#427fed</color>
    <color name="gplus_color_4">#b23424</color>

    <color name="holo_blue_dark">#0099cc</color>
    <color name="holo_yellow_dark">#ff8800</color>
    <color name="holo_green_dark">#669900</color>
    <color name="holo_purple_dark">#9933cc</color>
    <color name="holo_red_dark">#cc0000</color>

</resources>
```

Comment: Same issue here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope, Not yet, i removed all libs , still no solution .. Support design is working in standalone project, but not getting integrated in other project...

Hope google will fix it up soon ..

Comment: I was able to solve the issue for me. I'm in the process of replacing ActionbarSherlock with the AppCompat library. I thought I had removed all instances of ABS, but one of my 3rd party libraries was using ABS. Once I removed that library, the error went away. Check your project for multiple imports of ABS and/or support/AppCompat libraries. You can only have one of those three.